# How to attach js/css to a StreamField block when it is rendered?

Tags: wagtail

I know that you can include javascript in the *form* by using the django forms Media API and the `js_initializer()` method, and I've done so successfully. But I need to include a javascript and CSS file in the page when an instance of this custom block I've written gets *displayed*.

Is there a specific mechanism for that? Or do I just need to include the js/css files in the Page template? I'd really like to avoid including them on every single Page which has a StreamField that *might* have this block, since the vast majority won't, and that means a lot of wasted page load time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was previously discussed at https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/2490 - I haven't tried it, but I believe you could implement this by defining a `frontend_media` property on the relevant block classes that returns a [django.forms.Media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/media/#media-objects) object, along with a function (a method on the page model is probably a good fit...) that collects those media definitions into a single object:

```
from django.forms import Media

class MyPage(Page):
    body = StreamField(...)

    def body_media(self):
        media = Media()
        for block_val in self.body:
            if hasattr(block_val.block, 'frontend_media'):
                media += block_val.block.frontend_media
        return media
```

Comment: Oh awesome, that's just what I was looking for! And incidentally, that issue you linked reminded me that my shop really should be using `{% compress %}` blocks instead of optional CSS/JS. I need to look into how to do that appropriately.